# Switch between program windows by default when clicking the taskbar icon

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

The default behavior for grouped Windows 7 taskbar icons is that when you click them, a list of thumbnails appears and you have to click again to pick one.

Another method is doing Ctrl-click which, when done repeatedly, selects one of the windows right away.

Is it possible to switch the default behavior for the Ctrl+ one? I want to click the icon and have one of the windows get to the front without clicking any thumbnails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It IS possible!

[Check out 7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/?proj=29):

> Features:
>
> - Show standard window menu on right click instead of jump list.
> - Close or focus a window on middle click instead of running a new
>     instance.
> - Disable grouping of windows by file path or application id.
> - Cycle through windows of a grouped button on left click instead of
>     showing a thumbnails preview.
> - Open with while dropping a file on a taskbar button instead of pinning.
> - Disable thumbnail previews.

[image: screenshot]

It's awesome; I can't use Windows 7 without this any more, especially on my tablet pc.